# Using RestKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I have successfully added 'RestKit' pod into my project and also followed steps described in this article: [Cocoapods in swift](https://medium.com/@kirualex/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc). I imported the RestKit into my `ViewController` class's source file:

```
import RestKit
```

But I don't know why I can't access it. It doen't show any of the classes in the RestKit. It shows:

> 'RestKit' No such module exists.

---

I tried again creating a new project and added 'RestKit'. and created a bridging header and imported 'RestKit' into ViewController claas's source file. Now i run the project
it shows errors like

```
 //  in this file Pods-SOCKit-prefix.pch

    #ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #endif

    #import "Pods-environment.h" // Pods-environment.h file not found

 //  and also in this file Pods-TransitionKit-prefix.pch


    #ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #endif

    #import "Pods-environment.h" // Pods-environment.h file not found
```

If someone knows what's the problem behind this, please explain it to me, and suggest a way to work with RestKit in Swift.

Comment: Try look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736739/restkit-coredata-and-swift-i-cant-seem-to-fetch-results-back-out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what the Cocoapods problem you are having. I added RestKit to my bridging header and didn't need to add `import RestKit` to my Swift file.

My bridging header looks like the following:

```
# if you are using Core Data:
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

#import <RestKit/RestKit.h> 

# if you are using Core Data:   
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
```

Comment: #import <RestKit/CoreData.h> first, than #import <RestKit/RestKit.h>  if you are not importing core data in bridging header